# Unix Copy Command

Tags: unix, command-line, copy

I am learning unix and I had a doubt which might sound silly but shooting it out.

I created a directory, let's call it `dir1` & created a subdirectory of `dir1` named `dir2`. In `dir1` I created some files as well such as `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`, `f6`, `f7`, `f8`, `f9`.

Now if i need to copy all the files of `dir1` to `dir2`. I tried this command

```
cp f* ./dir2
```

and it worked.

Now what if I don't know the name of any file and want to copy all files of `dir1` to `dir2`. I tried using the `find` command but it's not working:

```
find . -type f | xargs cp
```

I also tried this command:

```
cp * ./dir2
```

Help me out ;)

Comment: technically you could just do `cp dir1/* dir1/dir2/.`. It will print out saying you cannot copy directories, but this will be just noise.

Comment: Ty ; it worked.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that comes to my mind is make a for loop. copy all the files, skip directories.

```
for in in $(ls -l|grep -v ^d|awk '{print $9}'); do cp $i dir2; done
```

do the same thing using find (more advanced but cleaner code)

```
find . -type f | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' dir2
```

Comment: I did understand the concept of yours thanks for help

Comment: awesome ! Was looking for this only.Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding your file structure is as follows?

```
dir1/
    dir2/
    f1
    f2
    f3
```

If you want to do a simple copy of all of the files from `dir1` to `dir2` you can just do the following:

```
cp dir1/* dir1/dir2/.
```

This will automatically ignore directories as you are not using the `-r` (recursive) flag.

If you want to silence the error message then you can redirect the STDERR to `/dev/null`.

```
cp dir1/* dir1/dir2/. 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: i am testing the chmod command

I tried the following commands,and both worked

CHMOD u+rwx,g+x,o+r FILE1
 or
CHMOD 712 FILE1 

But now i need to reset it to default as same  permissions when i created it .

Comment: The usual default for files is 644, and for folders is 755. However, I don't think asking this as a comment to an answer, where the answer is to different question, is the way to do it.